# How can I covert milliseconds (unix timestmap) to utc php

Tags: php

I am creating `web services` for android in php, they are sending time in `unix timestamp` (milliseconds).

Now I need to convert this in utc timestamp and compare with mysql created_at.

I have tried that:

```
$time = 1443001794;
$seconds = $time / 1000;
echo date("d-m-Y", $seconds);
```

But it always returns '17-01-1970'.

Comment: Use strtotime for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you only want to compare with `mysql` timestamp then you can do like this:

```
$result = strtotime($mysqlCreateAt);
```

`strtotime` will convert your timestamp in unix timestamp, and then you can compare with any time you want.

**If you want to convert this to utc, try this:**

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1443001794);
var_dump(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
```

It will give to `UTC` timestamp

Answer (score 3):

*MYSQL date format is "yyyy-mm-dd":*

**So simply use this:**

```
$time = 1443001794;
echo  date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

**If You want date with time . Then Try this**

```
$time = 1443001794;
echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare then you can just use `strtotime` for that.

```
$db_time = strtotime($created_at); // it will convert your db created at in unix
if($unixtime > $db_time){
 // your code here
}
```